# selenium ide export to webdriver java

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

The "Java - WebDriverBackedSelenium" exporter I found generates code 
like this: 
    selenium.open("/"); 
    selenium.type("Password", "blah"); 
etc..

But I need it to export like the classic WebDriver example below:

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
element.sendKeys("Cheese!");
```

is there a way to export to the 2nd option? I'm being asked to use this, and have used the ide to get
the page id tags in the past, it would be nice to export to this format if possible. Does anyone know
or have any opinions on this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can export the recorded Selenium tests as "JUnit 4 (WebDriver)" tests instead of "JUnit 4 (WebDriver Backed)" tests, if you need to use the `WebDriver` API class alone and not `Selenium` class in your tests.

PS: It would also help to use a more up to date version of the Selenium IDE; v.1.2.0 (which is the most recent version of the IDE as of now) definitely supports exporting tests cases to use the WebDriver API.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm using the latest IDE 1.2.0 and I don't have a option for exporting to JUnit 4 WebDriver that is not a Backed option. Should that be a default option downloaded with the IDE?

Comment: Yes, I would assume that the "JUnit 4 (WebDriver)" is a default format that comes with the IDE. It is typically available in the `File` menu under the `Export Test Case As...` option.

Comment: @Green, You might want to verify if you have the `Selenium IDE: Java Formatters 1.2.0` extension installed in your Firefox profile. Also, you might want to take a look at [this Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/webdriver-backed-formatters/) although I did not require it's installation to get the formatters.

Comment: Yeah I do that, so I removed it and reinstalled the plugin, it showed up after I did that, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Whilst on the IDE do the following...

- Click File
- Export Test Case As...
- Select Java / TestNG / WebDriver
- Give the file a name, and ensure you put .java at the end of it e.g. test.java